# Which group do two generic $2\times 2$ triangular matrices generate?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

Let $A,B$ be two generic (in particular invertible) $2\times 2$ upper-triangular complex matrices. They generate  a countable group $G$, the commutator subgroup of $G$ is abelian. Are there other relations in $G$? How is this group called?

Comment: What do you call "relation" in a group? "The commutant of any two generic element is abelian" is not usually called a relation.

Comment: any two commutators commute, it is kind of relation, is not it?

Comment: Oh, what you call the commutant is known as the derived subgroup (or you mean the set of commutators), but "commutant" means something else, namely centralizer ([Wikipedia bicommutant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicommutant)).

Comment: You need to fix the size $k$ of matrices. The group is, I think, isomorphic to the (relatively) free group on two generators in the group variety (in the sense of universal algebra) generated by the group of $k\times k$ upper triangular matrices (over $\mathbf{C}$, but this variety does depend on the choice of field of characteristic zero). For instance for $k=1$ this is a free abelian group in 2 generators and for $k=2$ this is a free metabelian group on 2 generators (but for $k=3$ it will not be free 3-solvable on 2 generators as the latter is not linear).

Comment: Oops, I just noticed you stick to $k=2$. Then you get the free metabelian group on 2 generators. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Indeed, I used the wrong terminology, I meant the commutator subgroup (=the derived subgroup), now fixed. It is called "the commutant of a group" (коммутант группы) in Russian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is a old result of Magnus that the free metabelian group on $d$ generators can be embedded as group $T_2$ of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbf{C}$.

It is easy to deduce that

> every generic $d$-tuple in $T_2$ freely generates such a free metabelian group $\Gamma_d$.

Here generic means: not in some countable union of proper Zariski closed subsets of $T_2^d$; hence it's generic both in the topological and the measured sense.

Indeed, let $w(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ be a nontrivial element $\Gamma_d$. Let $F_w$ be the set of $d$-tuples $g\in T_2^d$ such that $w(g)=I_2$. Then $F_w$ is a proper Zariski closed subset. Hence any $d$-tuple outside $\bigcup_{w\in\Gamma_d-\{1\}}F_w$ works.

(A group is metabelian if its derived subgroup is abelian, or equivalently if and only if any two commutators commute. So it doesn't mean a free metabelian group satisfies no other relation, but it indeed means that all its relations can be derived from this one.)

Comment: thank you! of course by "other relations" I meant "relations not implied by..."